# Get the word after matching certain Expression

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to get the word "1.23" from this string.

The String is

"1 USD in SGD 1.23".

I know regex can find words but I want to get the number after the SGD which is "1.23".

Thanks.

Comment: What environment (language) are you operating in? Your question is tagged `grep`, but as far as I know grep is only capable of returning complete lines. Also, different regex implementations use different syntaxes.

Comment: Grep can return more than complete lines, using the `-o` switch, e.g. `$ echo 1 USD in SGD 1.23 | grep -o [0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Do you need a regexp for this? If its the last part of a string `cut` or `awk` is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The regex could be something like: `\bSGD\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`, but what works with grep I'm not sure.

With perl you could do grep-like stuff:

```
cat foo.txt | perl -n -e '/\bSGD\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/ && print "$1\n"'
```

Comment: Thanks! ;) (Was using the pipe there in case he was piping something to grep.)

Answer (score 1):

Works with `-P` (for `Perl regular expression`) :

```
grep -P "(?<=\bSGD)\s*1\.23"
```